# Error with node app, using Digital Ocean and FlightPlan.js - All configured authentication methods failed

Tags: node.js, ssh, digital-ocean

I'm using [flightplan.js](https://github.com/pstadler/flightplan) and digital ocean and following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxRuW1pfGTI),  but then I get this error:

```
rendezvousNode $ fly production 
✈ Running default:production
✈ Executing local task
localhost Copy files to remote hosts
localhost $ git ls-files
localhost ● ok
localhost $ rsync --files-from /var/folders/vf/38fsn66x58z04p9jkhkwbspm0000gn/T/ad78ad3f4a7594e09f3542d82fb76731 -az --rsh="ssh -p22" ./ deploy@162.243.118.234:/tmp/rendeznode-1455004290008
localhost ● ok
✈ Local task finished after 17 s
✈ Connecting to '162.243.118.234'
● Error connecting to '162.243.118.234': All configured authentication methods failed
rendezvousNode $ ls
```

Comment: https://blog.gaya.ninja/articles/simple-node-js-web-server-digitalocean/ Is a great article and a different approach to building a simple node web server with digital ocean

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent and store your passphrase in the keychain.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```